# How to get cacert validation for terraform provisioners windows

Tags: windows, openssl, terraform, winrm, cacerts

I trying to deploy some packages in windows OS through terraform 15.1 version.
And I am able to deploy successful deployment when I use this in provisioners

```
Connection {
      type     = winrm
      user     = administrator
      password = ########
      timeout  = "3m"
      port     = 5986
      https    = true
      insecure = true
      host     = self.access_ip_v4
    }
```

but my goal to achieve is that the connection should be encrypted from where we are running terraform command to
remote windows machine

So, I want to use some thing like

```
 connection {
      type     = winrm
      user     = administrator
      password = ########
      timeout  = "3m"
      port     = 5986
      https    = true
      **insecure = false**
      **cacert   = <from where I can this file or value >**
      host     = self.access_ip_v4
    }
```

Remember that through terraform "user_data" I am using one Powershell script which create self certificate, open wirnrm https firewall port for winrm at the time of window provision.

I have not complete idea how to get this cacert for window.
Please can someone help me in this.

Comment: "insecure" is still encrypted, it's just not validating the trust of the SSL cert.

Comment: @jordanm IN Case  encryption will work
if  set  to
`insecure = true`  (What happen in that case ) 
or
`insecure = false` (What happen in that case)